# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts login form

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms

I am attempting to create a login page for my C# windows forms application.
I am using a local database (.sdf file called LWADataBase) with a table (passwordTBL) with username and password columns.

My code is :

```
private void loginBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string myConnection = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf";
        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
        MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from LWADataBaseDataSet.passwordTBL where Username ='" + this.usernameTxt.Text + "' and Password ='" + this.passwordTxt.Text + "';", myConn);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        myConn.Open();
        myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        if (count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Sucessful");
        }
        else if (count > 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate username or password. Access Denied");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect. Access Denied");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

When I debug and either enter or not enter anything into the textboxes diaplyed on the form, I get the error message "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts"

Am I using an incorrect connection string?
When I configure the data source with the wizard I get this connection string :
Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf

But when I click Database Explorer >(Right click)Properties I get this connection string:
Data Source=C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Lewis Warby Airbrushing\Lewis Warby Airbrushing\Lewis Warby Airbrushing\LWADataBase.sdf

Any suggestions?

Comment: I changed the Using statement from

    using System.Data.SqlClient;

to

    using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

Then changed all classes from "MySql" to "SqlCe"

e.g MySqlConnection is now SqlCeConnection

and it works sucessfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Using statement from

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

to

```
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
```

Then changed all classes from "MySQL" to "SqlCe"

e.g MySqlConnection is now SqlCeConnection

and it works sucessfully